# Excel VBA - Autofill method of range class failed

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to autofill to a variable but I'm getting "Autofill method of range class failed".

Here's the offending code:

```
    Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastRow2 As Long
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow2 = Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'change where this is accordingly

'Delete columns
   ActiveSheet.Range("C1,D1,F1,G1,H1,I1,L1,M1,R1,S1,V1,W1,Y1,Z1,AA1,AB1,AE1,AF1").EntireColumn.Delete


    Columns("J:J").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    Range("E10, T10").Value = "Full Name"
    Range("E11").Formula = "=CONCATENATE(C11 , "" "" , D11)"
    Range("E11").AutoFill Destination:="E11:" & lastRow  'THIS LINE THROWS THE ERROR
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: `"E11:" & lastRow` you need a column? Add an `E`? Edit: Scott articulated far better than I.

Comment: you are missing a column reference: `Range("E11").AutoFill Destination:="E11:E" & lastRow`.  you were missing the second `E`.

Comment: I added the E but it still throws the error.

Comment: Is `lastRow` > 11?

Comment: It still threw the error so I thought if it's < 11, it will break since you're starting on `E11`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure to declare `E11:E[lastRow]` as a range:

`Range("E11").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E11:E" & lastRow)`

Comment: lololololololol Edit: can't speak for Scott but I am gonna go hide in shame now. Edit2: but you missed the second `E` =P

Comment: You still need to add the second `E`; `Range("E11:E" & lastRow)` but yes I am ashamed of myself. Good catch.

Comment: Now it's throwing "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed... :\  Thanks so far though!

Comment: @ScottCraner - Thanks, I was about to edit, but you're quick!

Comment: I figured you were busy counting your billions, and a schlub like me could take care of the minutia in your life.